# Weird bug - Parameter not being passed in route in cucumber for ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am getting the strangest cucumber bug for when I test my ruby on rails app.  I have the function working perfectly on localhost.  I have a few steps in a couple of scenarios that check if I'm on a certain page, specifically the template for users#show.  So I wrote the step def and added the path in paths.rb and managed to get the first of such step to pass.  However, the other steps fail, in spite of using the exact same path, a fact that I verified with a raise.

Here are the steps:

from scenario 3: passes

```
Then I should be on the "jadams" profile page
```

from scenario 2: fails

```
And I am on the "testuser" profile page
```

from scenario 3: fails

```
And I go to the "testuser" profile page
```

Here's the step defs they use:

```
Then /^(?:|I )should be on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name)
end

When /^(?:|I )go to (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name)
end
```

And the path I defined:

```
when /^the "([^\"]*)" profile page$/i
  user_path(User.find_by_username($1))
```

I verified that they all reach this path and that a user is found and has an id.  I even tried using `/users/1` directly.  Yet I get this:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil}
```

Can anyone see why one of these steps are passing and the others are not? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, someone wrote a bad step def for the step before the ones that failed.